# Is the face on the front of the truck a Marvel approved likeness of the Green Goblin?

Tags: props, maximum-overdrive

In [*Maximum Overdrive*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091499/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt), the main antagonist of the film is a truck with the likeness of the Green Goblin face attached to the grille.

[image]

According to [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091499/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv), the face is *based* on the Green Goblin:

> The head on the main truck is based on that of Marvel Comics' Green
>   Goblin.

The [Villain Wikia](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Happy_Toyz_(Green_Goblin)_Truck) page for the truck claims that Marvel actually gave permission for the likeness to be used in the film:

> The film crew had permission from Marvel to use the Green Goblin's
>   appearance for the mask.

However, I cannot seem to locate the source of this claim made on the wikia site.

**Is the face on the front of the truck a Marvel approved likeness of the Green Goblin or was it just *based* on the Green Goblin?**

---

Note:  I am looking for credible sources either from Marvel or from filmmakers.

Comment: I'm guessing that the necessary permission notice would be listed in the credits somewhere.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3951/49).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### They had permission from Marvel

According to [this source](http://www.cbr.com/comic-book-legends-revealed-584/3/) and the credits of the movie, they did have permission from marvel to use Green Goblin's face. Check this image from the credits of the movie:

[image: Credits]

It reads in part:

> Marvel Comics' "Green Goblin" (and his distinctive likeness) is a trademark of the Marvel Comics Groups and is used with Permission.

Comment: 1986 was of course long before Marvel started making their push into theatrical releases of their material that we are all so familiar with today.  They had only set up a California operation 5 years earlier, and were mostly concentrating on animated TV. So getting such permission back then likely wouldn't have been nearly the ordeal one might expect it to be today.

Comment: [Congratulations, for the 1st runner up Rewards for the best answer of 3rd quarter of 2017](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-3rd-quarter-of-2017)